# XAMPP / WordPress on OSX Sierra hangs/slow sometimes on plugin upgrades

Tags: wordpress, macos, curl, xampp

I am running the most recent xampp/wordpress setup on my mac OSX (currently upgraded to Sierra). Generally speaking the whole setup works fine.

But sometimes (often enough to be frustrating), operations to do with adding new plugins, or upgrading plugins, seem to hang. When they work, the operations are very fast, like normal ops. But sometimes the plugin operations (upgrades or add new) just hang xampp in .maintenance mode.

It feels like a name lookup timeout. Once I saw a cURL 6: error, which was a name lookup. I've been fighting the problem for a month, without success, even after reading 100+ posts on the net (none of them were exactly on my problem).

When the problem occurs, xampp (or wordpress) hangs, after putting the wp site in .maintenance mode. Usually I have to manually remove the .maintenance file to get things going again (with the plugin operation still not finished).

Othertimes, the plugin operations are lightning fast, as expected.

`To date, I have:
- disabled ipV6 in /etc/hosts (commented out the ::1 line)
- ensured that '127.0.0.1 mac.local' is in /etc/hosts
- added '-ip4' in ~/.curlrc`

I'm at the end of my rope. Everything on the mac (including sometimes the plugin/upgrade/addnew operations) works fine for the most part. But the hanging plugin ops (sometimes login ops too) are driving me nuts.

Does anyone have any better ideas to try? Any ideas on how I can nail down the exact problem? And then KILL it?

Thanks, Kevin

Extra info: I am not sure this is related, because things work normally. But I include it here, just in case. I don't know how to fix this error, since I just clicked the buttons and a default install of xampp. I made no changes to any of the default installation parameters, as far as I can remember.

logs/error_log:[Sun Oct 16 13:13:50.956969 2016] [core:error] [pid 56868] [client 127.0.0.1:58150] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http: //mac.local/wordpress/wp-admin/plugin-install.php

One of the net postings said that he changed 'mac.local' to 'mac.xxx' because on a mac, the .local top level domain is used for the Bonjour service. But I don't even know how to change the .local domain either. (And why would it work half the time anyway, even with .local?)

Comment: It seems to me that wordpress must do something different for plugin operations. It must use some programs, or do some operations, that require a different name lookup path. Or maybe it uses a name lookup cache of some kind (since half the time the plugin operations work fine).